# How to use variable in HTML and send email via bash

Tags: bash, email, sed

This is `email.html`:

```
# some html code here
<p style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>$line</p>
# some other html code here
```

Suppose a file like this in which I have `for` loop:

```
while read -r line
do
    grep -q $line > names
    cat < email.html | mail -a "Content-Type: text/html" -s "This Email Is For $(cat names)" myemail@gmail.com
done < file
```

This is `file`:

```
David
Jones
Rose
Saeed
```

I expect when I send email, I see four different emails with a red paragraph containing four different name, but I see a red `$line` in the email visually.

Is there anyway to do that? I googled a lot but didn't find a way. Or I should use other programming languages like Python?

Comment: Bash, sed, grep for html email. Those are all wrong tools. Even if you manage to get it apparently working right-now, it will bite you back with issues, some mundane issues like poor deliverability, some very serious ones like code injection and execution. There are probably more suitable scripting languages choices like Python, Perl, Php to get this done to the letter, without risking compromising safety or operation.

Comment: You could use [envsubst](https://linux.die.net/man/1/envsubst) to replace the variable by its value. Note that this would require you to make `line` an **environment** variable.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure the purpose of the `grep -q $line > names`, but as for the substitution requirement ...

You need to use something like `sed` to replace the literal `$line` with the value in the `bash` variable named `line`.

On idea:

```
while read -r line
do
    echo "######## $line"
    sed "s/\$line/$line/g" email.html
done < file
```

This generates:

```
######## David
# some html code here
<p style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>David</p>
# some other html code here
######## Jones
# some html code here
<p style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>Jones</p>
# some other html code here
######## Rose
# some html code here
<p style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>Rose</p>
# some other html code here
######## Saeed
# some html code here
<p style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>Saeed</p>
# some other html code here
```

Once you've confirmed the replacement is behaving as expected you could pipe the `sed` output to your `mail` call, eg:

```
sed "s/\$line/$line/g" email.html | mail -a "Content-Type: text/html" -s "This Email Is For ${line}" myemail@gmail.com
```

**NOTES:**

- I'm assuming your original `$(cat names)` is supposed to be the current content of the `bash` variable named `line` ... ???
- I'm not setup with outgoing `mail` support on my current env so I've just copied your `mail` call as is (ie, I haven't verified the accuracy of the `mail` call)

Comment: It worked as expected, thanks:) The reason of `grep -q $line > names` was for having log (I think that wasn't necessary in the question). And yes, `$(cat names)` contains the current `$line` variable.